# How to compile generated and non-generated classes in gradle when they are dependent?

Tags: gradle, thrift

How to compile generated and non-generated classes in gradle when non-generated classes(.java) are dependent on generated classes(.java)?

My generated classes are in $buildDir/generated-sources/thrift
My non generated classes are in src/main/java

The generated classes (.java files) are need to compile the non generated classes (.java files again) to finally put everything under $buildDir/classes/main (all .class files should be here)

Another way to say this would be my non generated classes in (src/main/java) need generated classes as a library dependency (.class files) to compile and run. So far I have the below build.gradle file but it doesn't quite work

```
plugins {
  id "org.jruyi.thrift" version "0.3.1"
}
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: "org.jruyi.thrift"

group 'com.peernova'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile files('/usr/local/lib/thrift-0.9.2.jar')
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.12'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    //compile files("$buildDir/classes/main") {
        builtBy 'compileThrift'
    }
}

def generatedDir = "$buildDir/generated-sources/thrift"

compileThrift {
    thriftExecutable "/usr/local/bin/thrift"
    //sourceDir "src/main/thrift"
    sourceDir "$buildDir/../../../lib/service_api"
    createGenFolder false
}

task thrift(type: Exec) {
    commandLine '/usr/local/bin/thrift'
}

compileJava {
    dependsOn 'compileThrift'
}

task(run_server, dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec) {
    if ( project.hasProperty("appArgs") ) {
        args Eval.me(appArgs)
    }
    main = 'com.apple.project.servicehandlers.server'
    classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
}

idea.module.sourceDirs += file("build/generated-sources/thrift")
```

Comment: Why not compile all files after generation?

Comment: How do you do that given my project structure?